# Protractor JS failing to click on HREF

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to simulate click on the link href.  I'm testing an application written with angular that will prompt users to enter their username and password.  After user successfully login, the application will display the main view page and in the page there is HREF link to open an overview page, but I'm unable to simulate click on HREF.

app:

```
<a _ngcontent-kdx-c2="" href="javascript:void(0)">Overview</a>
```

test:

```
element(by.linkText("Overview")).click();// not working
element(by.partialLinkText("Overview")).click();//not working also
```

and this is the error:

- Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60841980/8903949

Comment: @BharathKumarS, thanks for your response.  After I use browser.ignoreSynchronization & browser.wait()  before the click, the click on link is working.. thanks alot.